# Check installed apps version

Tags: ios, xcode, url-scheme

We have multiple apps in place for a company. Now we would like to write an 'Overview App' which should list all apps, differentiate between installed and not installed.

This can be achieved with an URL-Scheme, but:

We also want to check, if the **latest version of each app is installed**.

I first thought of using two schemes, one to check if the app is installed and a second with the version/bundle in the URL to check if it is the correct version.

What I found out yet:

1. As of iOS 9, third party applications are no longer able to query arbitrary URL schemes.
2. Info.plist Schemes cannot be edited on runtime

This will therefore not work in my opinion (Only if the overview app is updated with the new version scheme everytime one of the apps within is updated). The only alternative I could think of would be to implement a pod in each app which will on app start post the installed version/bundle with the device-id in an overview table which can then be accessed by the 'Overview App'.

This would be my very last solution if nothing else works, any inputs if I missed anything (with URL-Scheme, like Callback or something, or an other way) are highly appreciated.